# How to use AppDispatch type in in Redux async thunk?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

In my Redux async thunks, I want to use the AppDispatch type that is inferred as described here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript

I followed the instructions here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#typing-createasyncthunk

But when using this AppDispatch type in my custom ThunkApiConfig type (`MyThunkApiConfig` in the following example), there will be a circular reference as demonstrated here: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-joliot-ho45h?file=/src/usersSlice.ts:

`'dispatch' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.`

Which makes sense, since there is a circular dependency between the dispatch type and the used thunks. But then how can I use AppDispatch in the async thunk?

Thanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: This is definitely an unusual setup.  What is the goal of making `createAsyncSlice` take the async thunk as an argument rather than just using the variable directly?  I can for sure figure out the types but I'm not getting the point.

Comment: The type is of `dispatch` is `DispatchForMiddlewares<M> & Dispatch<A>` where `M` is the middleware and `A` is the action type.  I need to look up what the type is for the thunk middleware.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with using `AppDispatch` in your `MyThunkApiConfig` type.  The problem comes about when you do that *and also* define your slice as a function of the async action.  This causes a tight coupling between the slice types and the dispatch type which should not exist.

If the reducer is `usersSlice.reducer` then there is no problem.  This version *uses* the `updateUser` aynsc thunk, which in turn uses the typed dispatch.  But the type for the slice does not depend on the dispatch type.  It is only concerned with the types for the state and the actions that it creates (in this case, none).

Your `createAsyncSlice` on the other hand uses `MyThunkApiConfig` in its argument type.  So this creates a circle where the store type depends on the slice type and the slice type depends on the store type.

I fundamentally don't get what you are trying to achieve by passing the `updateUser` aysnc thunk through a function instead of just using it directly.  Obviously the easy solution here is "don't do that".

---

If you wanted to assign the type for `AppDispatch` directly, you can of course do that.  It's not recommended because the types are complex and rely on a lot of generic type parameters.

```
export type RootState = { users: UsersState }
export type AppDispatch = Dispatch<AnyAction> & ThunkDispatch<RootState, null, AnyAction>
```

---

In your example you don't actually need the `MyThunkApiConfig` at all.  You could just drop the generics from `updateUser`.  They will end up being inferred as `<User, void, {}>` which is sufficient.  You could type your slice argument as `asyncThunk: AsyncThunk<User, void, {}>` and that would also fix the circular typings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
- Sorry, I forgot to clarify the purpose of the generic createAsyncSlice function. It serves for extracting the common functionality of storing the state of async thunks, much like https://diode.suzaku.io/advanced/Pot.html.
- Unfortunately if I don't use MyThunkApiConfig but `asyncThunk: AsyncThunk<User, void, {}>` instead, `action.payload` will be of `unknown` type.
- So if I understand correctly, you're suggesting to fall back to manually specifying both `RootState` and `AppDispatch` in this case, do you?